# Find elements above and below given number in object

Tags: javascript

I have object like below

```
[
  {
    "value": 14,
    "name": "vwap"
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "name": "yopen"
  },
  {
    "value": 12,
    "name": "open"
  },
  {
    "value": 13,
    "name": "s3"
  },
  {
    "value": 9,
    "name": "fr1"
  },
  {
    "value": 10,
    "name": "fr2"
  }
]
```

If my input is 9 , I need output as `1,9 and 10,12,13`
If my input is 13 , I need output `1,9,10,12,13 and 14`

Output should be 2 seperate objects like `{ "value": 10, "name": "fr2" }` ,Also output should be sorted.

I tried something like below , but it works only for array.

```
function getVal(array, val, dir) {
  for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (dir == true) {
      if (array[i] > val){
        return array[i-1] || 0;
      }
    } else {
      if (array[i] >= val) {
        return array[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In first example input `9` is included in result but in second example `13` input is not not included in output. Why? And _"Output should be 2 seperate objects"_ I think it should be arrays.

Comment: Sorry my bad , I have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and check if given number is less or greater than objects value and use `sort()` in end

```js
const arr = [ { "value": 14, "name": "vwap" }, { "value": 1, "name": "yopen" }, { "value": 12, "name": "open" }, { "value": 13, "name": "s3" }, { "value": 9, "name": "fr1" }, { "value": 10, "name": "fr2" } ]

function getParts(arr,num,min=0,max=Infinity){
  let first = arr.filter(x => num >= x.value && x.value > min && x.value < max).sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value);
  let second = arr.filter(x => num < x.value && x.value < max && x.value > min).sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value);
  return [first,second];
}

console.log(getParts(arr,9,5,12))
console.log('----------For 13--------------')
console.log(getParts(arr,13))
```

Another way is to `sort()` the array first and then `slice()` it.

```js
const arr = [ { "value": 14, "name": "vwap" }, { "value": 1, "name": "yopen" }, { "value": 12, "name": "open" }, { "value": 13, "name": "s3" }, { "value": 9, "name": "fr1" }, { "value": 10, "name": "fr2" } ]

function getParts(arr,num){
  let temp = arr.slice().sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value);
  let index = temp.findIndex(x => x.value === num);
  return [temp.slice(0,index+1),temp.slice(index)];
}

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getParts(arr,9))))
console.log('----------For 13--------------')
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getParts(arr,13))))
```

Comment: In your first solution , How do I have a limit , like I dont want array with values more than 12 and arrays with value less than 5 ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams You can have 2 other parameters for function `min` and `max` and then use two more conditions in `filter()`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you working smooth , how do i get result in descending upper part and lower part ? by sort(b,a) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could take acheck and push the object into the wanted array.

```js
function getParts(value) {
    return data.reduce((r, o) => (r[+(o.value > value)].push(o), r), [[], []]);
}

var data = [{ value: 14, name: "vwap" }, { value: 1, name: "yopen" }, { value: 12, name: "open" }, { value: 13, name: "s3" }, { value: 9, name: "fr1" }, { value: 10, name: "fr2" }];

data.sort(({ value: a }, { value: b }) => a - b);
console.log(getParts(9));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to store your result, containing both lower and upper parts.

Then, loop your array and compare the value against the input. You'll know where to store your element, in lower or upper part

```js
let datas = [{"value":14,"name":"vwap"},{"value":1,"name":"yopen"},{"value":12,"name":"open"},{"value":13,"name":"s3"},{"value":9,"name":"fr1"},{"value":10,"name":"fr2"}];

function getVal(input)
{
  let result =
  {
    lowerPart: [],
    upperPart: []
  };
  
  datas.forEach((elem) =>
  {
    if (elem.value <= input)
      result.lowerPart.push(elem);
    else
      result.upperPart.push(elem);
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(getVal(9));

console.log(getVal(13));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce()`

```js
var arr = [{"value":14,"name":"vwap"},{"value":1,"name":"yopen"},{"value":12,"name":"open"},{"value":13,"name":"s3"},{"value":9,"name":"fr1"},{"value":10,"name":"fr2"}]

function getVal(arr, find) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, i) => {
    acc[i.value <= find ? 'l' : 'g'].push(i)
    return acc
  }, {
    l: [],
    g: []
  })
}

console.log(getVal(arr, 9))

console.log(getVal(arr, 13))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Usage**

```
let res = getVal(arr, 9)
res.l // lowerpart
res.g // greaterpart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter and sort function for your requirement.

```
var find = 9;
var left = arr.filter(c=>c.value <= find).sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value);
var right = arr.filter(c=>c.value > find).sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value);
```

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "value": 14,
    "name": "vwap"
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "name": "yopen"
  },
  {
    "value": 12,
    "name": "open"
  },
  {
    "value": 13,
    "name": "s3"
  },
  {
    "value": 9,
    "name": "fr1"
  },
  {
    "value": 10,
    "name": "fr2"
  }
]
var find = 9;
var left = arr.filter(c=>c.value <= find).sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value);
var right = arr.filter(c=>c.value > find).sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value);
console.log('Less than or equal: ' + find);
console.log(left)
console.log('Greater than: ' + find);
console.log(right)
```

Comment: How do I have a limit , like I dont want arrays more than 12 and arrays less than 5 ?

Comment: you can add condition arr.filter(c=> !(c.value >=12 && c < 5) && c.value <= 9)